# Add a delay on new style tooltips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-experience, tooltips

The new custom tooltips have no delay like native tooltips in browsers, file explorers, etc. as a result when scrolling up and down a page, especially with the cursor near the voting buttons, you can be bombarded with tooltips. With the new thanks feature on answers both questions and answers now have *5* elements which give instant tooltips, that means scrolling down a page with 4 answers you can expect to see **25** tooltips, rather than the usual 0:

[image]

And indeed on answers which have acceptance, bounties and reactions that turns into *8* (upvote, vote count, downvote, acceptance, bounties, say thanks, people who've reacted with thanks, and the timeline):

[image]

This is annoying and distracting from the site, as well as not being consistent with the rest of the browsing (and computing in general) experience.

Can we add a 1 second or so delay between the hover event and the tooltip appearing?

Comment: also a way to disable them ... it's annoying especially for someone already used to all this actions

Comment: Same [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349530/please-add-a-delay-to-the-hover-tooltips) on Meta.

Comment: Tooltips are supposed to be on a delay that is based on your system's double-click time. This is how all operating systems' window managers work. It's good to see that Stack Overflow has idle developers with time to re-invent the wheel, but I wish they would consult me instead. I can give them some higher-priority tasks to work on than building inferior replacements for native browser features. These tooltips are a horribly annoying abomination. Not just because of the lack of delay and the failure to conform to system settings, but also because they're so horizontally compressed.

Comment: See, e.g., [Microsoft's documentation for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tooltip-controls): *"The cursor must hover over a tool for a period of time before the tooltip is displayed. The default duration of this timeout is controlled by the user's double click time and is typically about one-half second. To specify a non-default timeout value, send the tooltip control a [TTM_SETDELAYTIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ttm-setdelaytime) message."* (You can override the default delay time as a programmer, but you probably shouldn't.)

Comment: As you might expect, the inimitable Raymond Chen has blogged about this, too: [The double-click time tells the window manager how good your reflexes are](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080423-00/?p=22623)

Comment: I just added `stackoverflow.com##.s-popover__tooltip` to uBlock's custom filters. Blessed silence once again

Comment: Apparently users vote too much already, so I think this was done because Stack Overflow wants users to not bring their mouse close to any of those buttons. But thanks to Phil, I may now consider voting again.

Comment: @Bergi I've rolled back your change adding [meta-tag:bug] as I don't believe this _is_ a bug, I think it is the intended functionality by SO, whether or not that's what _should_ be done is another story, hence the use of [meta-tag:feature-request], a request to implement something _purposefully omitted_, not accidentally broken.

Comment: Also the tooltip text is blocked by an accessibility-enlarged cursor.

Comment: The tool tips I mean that can be blocked by a magnified cursor are the usual small ones, which I see don't have this large-popup non-waiting behaviour, maybe the usual small-popup ones are default. In which case the default is a problem for accessibility.

Comment: @philipxy The default tooltips are completely managed by the browser and the operating system. It's not something that websites can, or should, influence. If there's an accessibility issue with default tooltips, then that's something that needs to be solved by the the operating system, the browser, or, if you're using software to get the enlarged cursor, rather than a change to your operating system's configuration, then the solution may be in changes to that software, but it's not reasonable to expect every website to independently implement custom tooltips to solve *that* specific problem.

Comment: @philipxy On the other hand, if a website *does* implement custom tooltips, as is the case for the pseudo-tooltips being discussed here, then that implementation should take into account the need to accommodate the wide spectrum of possible system configuration changes, like the enlarged cursor you use. Note that it may not even be possible for the website to to determine that such a system configuration change exists, which is one of the reasons that tooltips are managed by the browser/OS.

Comment: I've made a similar request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398609/make-the-new-popups-when-hovering-over-votes-less-intrusive

Comment: I **HATE** these tooltips! Please give us an option to disable them or just wipe them off the face of the earth for everyone.

Comment: @camden_kid You can hide the pseudo tooltips on the items in the voting area by adding the CSS: `.votecell .s-popover {display: none;}`

Answer (score -10):

If the intent is to inform people who do not know the Stack Exchange paradigm, perhaps the delay could be graduated by reputation. This is a sample with toy values:

- **1 ≤ rep < 50** Appears immediately
- **50 ≤ rep < 150** Appears after 150ms
- **150 ≤ rep < 1k** Appears after 300ms
- **1k ≤ rep < 2.5k** Appears after 500ms
- **2.5k ≤ rep < ∞** Appears after 800ms or something

  - This tier is probably only doing it to take screenshots, anyway.

That way, you can point newcomers to the voting they ought to be doing, and leave the rest of us alone.