# Make the new popups when hovering over votes less intrusive

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting, tooltips

There are a couple of popups that show when hovering over different vote buttons:

> [image: popup that shows when hovering over the different vote buttons]

As it is right now, these appear on the right side of the buttons, hiding a significant part of the Q/A's content, as the popups are pretty large.

I find these popups to be rather intrusive. Frankly, I preferred having them as title attributes on the elements.

## Suggested changes:

- Move the popups to the left side of the elements.
  On larger screens there's a whole lot of real estate available. I have a userscript that does this for me:
  `jQuery('[data-s-tooltip-placement]').attr('data-s-tooltip-placement', 'left')`
- Add a small delay before the popups show.
- Add a small transition to the popup popping up.
- (Give us the option to) switch back to `title` attributes.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398386/add-a-delay-on-new-style-tooltips (duplicate for the delay)

Comment: Look at the hover popups for tags; they use the new style, yet also have a delay and fade-in animation.

Comment: They seem to have been completely removed.

Comment: Thanks for raising. We've been talking internally about this and we have plans to put in a delay or other change to make this less intrusive. It's on our list to address.

Comment: @JonChan It would be nice if you could make them a proper tooltip. Every system understand those.

Answer (score 19):

I have a userscript option to revert to native tooltips.

### Option 1: Disable Thanks Reactions and New Tooltips

The relevant excerpt from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398409 :

> Step 0 - Install a userscript manager browser extension:
>
> - Recommended https://www.tampermonkey.net
>
> Step 1 - Install/update userscript by clicking on this link:
>
> - https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ReduceClutter.user.js

### Option 2: Disable New Tooltips only

Step 0 - Install a [userscript manager](https://www.tampermonkey.net) browser extension

Step 1 - Install/update userscript by clicking on this link:

- https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/RevertTooltips.user.js

Comment: It'd be awesome if parts of it could be enabled / disabled, as there are some things in there I don't necessarily want reverted ;-)

Comment: I've split the revert tooltips bit into another userscript

Comment: Does it revert the pop-ups back to real tool-tips? :)

Comment: Yes it does,  @Scratte :D Thanks, Samuel!

Comment: uBlock rule to block the tooltips without a script: `##div[id^="--stacks-s-tooltip"]`

Comment: Perhaps it's just me. But the "RevertTooltips.user.js" script doesn't seem to work in review. I've tried it in First Posts.

Comment: @Scratte fixed both for reviews

Answer (score 11):

We added a small (300ms) delay to the tooltips. It feels like a good balance between being responsive and not being too annoying about it, and I hope you agree.