# How do I turnoff tooltips on voting buttons?

Tags: support

Those tooptips are annoying. How do I turn them off? I checked settings, couldn't find anything relevant. Please guide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the new popups when hovering over votes less intrusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398609/make-the-new-popups-when-hovering-over-votes-less-intrusive) (contains an answer with a userscript to turn them off)