# Tooltips are persistently visible on Safari

Tags: bug, status-review, design, tooltips, safari

Using Safari version 14.0.1 (16610.2.11.51.8), the tooltips on Stack Overflow are persistently visible (see attached screenshot) and cannot be dismissed.

[image: Shows tooltips from vote arrows, activity link, and follow link all stacked on top of each other]

Comment: Technically I don't think it's a tooptip. It seems to be an insta-custom-popup, which is better blocked by an extension. I think I've used `stackoverflow.com##div[id^="--stacks-s-tooltip"]` to block them, but their name may have changed. I think I have another `stackoverflow.com##.s-popover__tooltip` in my filter too, which I removed when I started using a user script instead, which you can find on [Make the new popups when hovering over votes less intrusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398609/make-the-new-popups-when-hovering-over-votes-less-intrusive)

Comment: More problems with the "roll your own tooltips". When will people learn? Use the standard elements, and an entire category of problems just evaporates. Not to mention usability, consistency, ... Reinventing the wheel often results in a hexagon shape.

Comment: Struggling to reproduce this one. Is this after hovering over those links, or were they shown when you loaded the page?

Comment: I'm also noticing something strange with the styling of those tooltip arrows. Hmm.

Comment: @AaronShekey, the tooltips show up for me on every post as soon as I load the page. I'm currently disabling all tooltips using the following custom CSS.

```.s-popover.s-popover__tooltip {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363206/safari-showing-popups-all-the-time || CC @AaronShekey

Comment: I was having this issue on Safari on MacOS and adding `.s-popover.s-popover__tooltip` to 1Blocker's CSS Hide Elements list did the trick.

Comment: @AaronShekey half year later, any update? Also, can you please mark the [MSE report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363206/safari-showing-popups-all-the-time) as [meta-tag:status-review] as well?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, disabling ReadCube Papers extension resolved this problem.