# How do I get rid of Stack Overflow pop-ups?

Tags: support, bug, tooltips

[image: screenshot]

How do I get rid of these pop ups that cover code?

Comment: Samuel Liew made a user script to get rid of them. It changes them back to real tool-tip. [RevertTooltips](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/RevertTooltips.user.js). It's linked from their Answer to [Make the new popups when hovering over votes less intrusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398611/12695027)

Comment: Move your mouse